# How to handle ajax request in php?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have line in my code

```
var auth = $.ajax("continue.php?act=login&login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&oldPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&captcha_key=" + captcha_key + "&captcha_sid=" + captcha_sid + "&validation_sid=" + validation_sid + "&code=" + smscode + "&newPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(g("newpassword").value) + "&is2fa=" + (have2fa ? 1 : 0) + "&qid=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.search) + "&token=" + gettedToken).done(function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(auth.responseText);
```

How I can handle this line it in php?Like...In continue.php I want to write a handler.

Comment: What do you mean with "How I can handle this line it in php" ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create the php whereever your server is located, then get the params you are sending with `$_GET['paramName']` or `filter_input()` and then in php do what ever you wanna do with those params

Comment: Can you clarify how canI use function filter_input() if i want to handle ajax request)
var auth = $.ajax("continue.php?act=login&login=" + encodeURIComponent(login) + "&oldPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(password) + "&captcha_key=" + captcha_key + "&captcha_sid=" + captcha_sid + "&validation_sid=" + validation_sid + "&code=" + smscode + "&newPassword=" + encodeURIComponent(g("newpassword").value) + "&is2fa=" + (have2fa ? 1 : 0) + "&qid=" + encodeURIComponent(window.location.search) + "&token=" + gettedToken).done(function() {
            var response = JSON.parse(auth.responseText);